# Poisson Process Probability Question

Tags: probability

The following is question taken from a set of lecture notes,

> Henry works for the council and is responsible for the up keep of speed cameras on roads in the area. Recently a particular camera has stop working, and Henry must go and repair it. However, to diagnose the issue and then complete the repairs, Henry must shut down the camera completely for 2 hours. The council tells Henry that the camera catches speeding drivers at a rate of 3 per hour.
>
> Henry arrives at the camera location at 8:45AM. After waiting 15 minutes, he observes no speeding drivers and decides to start his repairs. What is the probability that any speeding cars will pass the camera while it is down?
>
> You may assume that the passing of cars follows a Poisson process.

I'm having trouble trying to solve this problem. I believe it involves an exponential distribution since it asks for the probability any cars pass it in an interval of time.

I have,

Let $T$ be the number of hours between speeding cars. Let $T \sim \operatorname{Exp}(3)$.

$$\Pr( 9{:}00\text{ AM} < T < 11{:}00 \text{ AM}) = \Pr( 0.25 <T< 2.25) \text{ (where $8{:}45$ AM is $t=0$)}$$

I'm not really sure where to go next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Poisson processes the distribution of the waiting times is *memoryless* so all you need is to compute the probability of at least one arrival in the next 2 hours.

It is probably easiest to look at the Poisson process. An average of 3/h means an expected value of $\mu=6$ over 2 hours. You then need
$$
P(X\geq1)=1-P(X=0)=1-\frac{\mu^0 e^{-\mu}}{0!}=1-e^{-6}\approx0.9975.
$$
If you want to go the exponential route then consider that inter-arrival times follow an exponential distribution with mean $1/3$ (i.e., 20 minutes). You want to compute
$$
P(T<2)=1-e^{-\frac2{1/3}}=1-e^{-6}\approx0.9975.
$$

Comment: Do you mean $1 - Pr(X = 0)$? Thanks for the response too.

Comment: @R.Evet Yes ! fixed my answer.

Comment: Rather than saying "Poisson processes are memoryless", one should say that the distribution of the waiting times in Poisson processes is memoryless. The Poisson distribution is NOT memoryless and one could be misunderstood as saying that it is.